# IQ Custom provider not recognized

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, archive, provider

I am using **aSmack** with **Openfire**.

After a lot of research I found that Openfire doesn't support message archiving and installed the plugin **OpenArchive**.

Now archiving works fine and all the messages are stored fine.

Now in the client side I tried sending an **IQ stanza** to retrieve the **archived chats**.

First I added an IQ Provider like below:

`pm.addIQProvider("list", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ListIQProvider());`

Then I used:

```
final IQ iq = new IQ()
{

    @Override public String getChildElementXML()
    {

        return "<list  xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' with='test@customOpenfire.com'><set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'><max xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>30</max></set> </list>";

    }
};

iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
iq.setPacketID("987654321");

xmppConnection.sendPacket(iq);
```

It worked fine and I received the response.

```
<iq id="987654321" to="admin@customOpenfire.com/Smack" type="result">
<list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive">
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-06T12:11:28.674Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T16:55:59.523Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-05T16:33:03.377Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-02T14:32:10.499Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-06T12:47:52.961Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T14:46:24.877Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-06T12:37:14.608Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T15:48:46.642Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-02T13:46:07.750Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-04T18:25:57.968Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T19:08:45.238Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-04T18:47:19.067Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-04T19:34:27.819Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-02T15:09:13.140Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T18:30:36.804Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-05T14:09:34.973Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-04T22:47:54.363Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-02T15:32:44.540Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T17:18:37.940Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-03T13:37:15.630Z"/>
    <chat with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-04T17:10:39.116Z"/>

    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
        <first index="0">66</first>
        <last>139</last>
        <count>21</count>
    </set>
</list>
</iq>
```

Then I wanted to retrieve the actual messages so I sent this **IQ stanza**:

```
final IQ iq = new IQ()
{

    @Override public String getChildElementXML()
    {

        return "<retrieve  xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' with='test@customOpenfire.com'><set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'><max xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>30</max></set> </retrieve>";

    }
};

iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
iq.setPacketID("987654321");

xmppConnection.sendPacket(iq);
```

Of course after I created my custom provider and added it like below:

```
pm.addIQProvider("retrieve", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ChatIQProvider());
```

And I should have received something like:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="hgfg" to="admin@customOpenfire.com/7dd0f2fc">
<chat xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="test@customOpenfire.com" start="2014-04-02T13:46:07.750Z">
    <from secs="0" jid="test@customOpenfire.com">
        <body>hello</body>
    </from>
    <to secs="2">
        <body>hey</body>
    </to>
    <from secs="5" jid="test@customOpenfire.com">
        <body>test</body>
    </from>
    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
        <first index="0">0</first>
        <last>2</last>
        <count>3</count>
    </set>
</chat>
```

But in my packet listener the result isn't parsed and is treated just like the **list stanza** is treated if I remove the **ListIQProvider()**.

Here are my custom classes:

**ChatIQ:**

```
public class ChatIQ extends IQ {


private String xmlns;
private String with;
private String start;

private List<From> froms;
private Set set;

public ChatIQ()
{
    this.froms = new ArrayList<ChatIQ.From>();
}

public String getXmlns()
{
    return xmlns;
}

public void setXmlns(String xmlns)
{
    this.xmlns = xmlns;
}

public String getWith()
{
    return with;
}

public void setWith(String with)
{
    this.with = with;
}

public String getStart()
{
    return start;
}

public void setStart(String start)
{
    this.start = start;
}



public void addFrom(From from)
 {
    froms.add(from);
 }

 public List<From> getFroms()
 {
    return froms;
 }

public Set getSet()
 {
    return set;
 }

 public void setSet(Set set)
 {
    this.set = set;
 }

 @Override
 public String getChildElementXML()
 {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<chat xmlns=\"urn:xmpp:archive\"");
        builder.append("with=\"").append(with).append("\"");
        builder.append(" start=\"");
        builder.append(start);
        builder.append("\">");
        for(From from : froms)
        {
            builder.append(from.toXml());
        }
        builder.append(set.toXml());
        builder.append("</chat>");
        return builder.toString();
 }

 public static class From 
 {
     private String secs;
     private String jid;

     private Body body;

     public String getSecs()
    {
        return secs;
    }


    public void setSecs(String secs)
    {
        this.secs = secs;
    }


    public String getJid()
    {
        return jid;
    }


    public void setJid(String jid)
    {
        this.jid = jid;
    }


    public Body getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }


    public void setBody(Body body)
    {
        this.body = body;
    }


    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<from ");
        builder.append("secs=\"").append(secs).append("\" ");
        builder.append("jid=\"").append(jid).append("\" >");
        builder.append(body.toXml());
        builder.append("</from>");
        return builder.toString();
    }
 }

 public static class Body 
 {
     private String message;

    public Body(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Object toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<body>");
        builder.append(message);
        builder.append("</body>");
        return builder.toString();
    }
 }

 public static class Set {
    private int last;
    private int count;
    private int indexAtt;
    private int first;

    public Set()
    {
    }

    public int getLast()
    {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(int last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getIndexAtt()
    {
        return indexAtt;
    }

    public void setIndexAtt(int indexAtt)
    {
        this.indexAtt = indexAtt;
    }

    public int getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(int first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<set xmlns=\"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm\">");
        builder.append("<first index=\"").append(indexAtt).append("\">").append(first).append("</first>");
        builder.append("<last>").append(last).append("</last>");
        builder.append("<count>").append(count).append("</count>");
        builder.append("</set>");
        return builder.toString();
    }
 }

}
```

**ChatIQProvider:**

```
public class ChatIQProvider implements IQProvider {

 public ChatIQProvider()
 {
 }

 @Override
 public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception
 {
    Log.d("CHAT IQ PROVIDER", String.format("Received iq packet, namespace[%s], name[%s]", parser.getNamespace(), parser.getName()));
    ChatIQ iq = new ChatIQ();
    ChatIQ.Set set = new Set();
    boolean done = false;

    From from = new From();
    String secs = "", jid = "";
    while (!done)
    {
        int eventType = parser.next();
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("from"))
            {
                secs = parser.getAttributeValue("", "secs");
                jid = parser.getAttributeValue("", "jid");

                from = new From();

                iq.addFrom(from);
            }
            else if(parser.getName().equals("body") && from.getBody()==null)
            {
                ChatIQ.Body body = new Body(parser.nextText());
                from.setBody(body);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("first"))
            {
                int index = parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue("", "index"));
                set.setIndexAtt(index);
                int first = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setFirst(first);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("last"))
            {
                int last = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setLast(last);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("count"))
            {
                int count = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setCount(count);
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("chat"))
            {
                iq.setSet(set);
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return iq;
 }

 private int parseInt(String integer)
 {
    return Integer.parseInt((integer != null ? integer : "0"));
 }
}
```

My questions are as follow:

- Why isn't my custom IQProvider recognized?
- Can I get the received XML and parse it without going through IQproviders?
- Is there a simpler way to retrieve the archived messages from the server? Knowing that the messages exist and I do receive them in the client side I just can't find a way to get the content and parse it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue, and I forgot to post the answer here for other people who might have the same problem.
Anyway the fix is pretty simple. Instead of:

```
pm.addIQProvider("retrieve", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ChatIQProvider());
```

I should've used:

```
pm.addIQProvider("chat", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ChatIQProvider());
```

I have to register the name of the child tag of the IQ response and not the request, hence "chat" instead of "retrieve".

Hope this helps, as I could not find any examples on the use of custom IQ in the android smack api.

***Since the comment was too long I added it here.***

Here you go:

**ListIQProvider:**

```
public class ListIQProvider implements IQProvider {

 public ListIQProvider()
 {
 }

 @Override
 public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception
 {
    ListIQ iq = new ListIQ();
    ListIQ.Set set = new Set();
    boolean done = false;

    String with = "", start = "";
    while (!done)
    {
        int eventType = parser.next();
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("chat"))
            {
                with = parser.getAttributeValue("", "with");
                start = parser.getAttributeValue("", "start");
                iq.addChat(new Chat(with, start));
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("first"))
            {
                int index = parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue("", "index"));
                set.setIndexAtt(index);
                int first = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setFirst(first);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("last"))
            {
                int last = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setLast(last);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("count"))
            {
                int count = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setCount(count);
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("list"))
            {
                iq.setSet(set);
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return iq;
 }

 private int parseInt(String integer)
 {
    return Integer.parseInt((integer != null ? integer : "0"));
 }
```

}

**ListIQ:**

```
public class ListIQ extends IQ {

 private List<Chat> chats;

 private Set set;

 public ListIQ()
 {
    this.chats = new ArrayList<ListIQ.Chat>();
 }

 public Set getSet()
 {
    return set;
 }

 public void setSet(Set set)
 {
    this.set = set;
 }

 public void addChat(Chat chat)
 {
    chats.add(chat);
 }

 public List<Chat> getChats()
 {
    return chats;
 }

 @Override
 public String getChildElementXML()
 {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<list xmlns=\"urn:xmpp:archive\">");
    for (Chat chat : chats)
    {
        builder.append(chat.toXml());
    }
    builder.append(set.toXml());
    builder.append("</list>");
    return builder.toString();
 }

 public static class Chat {
    private String with;
    private String start;

    public Chat()
    {
    }

    public Chat(String with, String start)
    {
        this.with = with;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getWith()
    {
        return with;
    }

    public void setWith(String with)
    {
        this.with = with;
    }

    public String getStart()
    {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start)
    {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<chat with=\"");
        builder.append(with).append("\"");
        builder.append(" start=\"");
        builder.append(start);
        builder.append("\"/>");
        return builder.toString();
    }

 }

 public static class Set {
    private int last;
    private int count;
    private int indexAtt;
    private int first;

    public Set()
    {
    }

    public int getLast()
    {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(int last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getIndexAtt()
    {
        return indexAtt;
    }

    public void setIndexAtt(int indexAtt)
    {
        this.indexAtt = indexAtt;
    }

    public int getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(int first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<set xmlns=\"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm\">");
        builder.append("<first index=\"").append(indexAtt).append("\">").append(first).append("</first>");
        builder.append("<last>").append(last).append("</last>");
        builder.append("<count>").append(count).append("</count>");
        builder.append("</set>");
        return builder.toString();
    }
 }

}
```

---

I just use this class, to call `ServiceProviders.Register_Providers(ProviderManager.getInstance());` right after the Xmpp Connection is connected.

**ServiceProviders:**

```
public class ServiceProviders
{
    public static void Register_Providers(ProviderManager pm)
    {
        Log.e("PROVIDER", "START");
        // Private Data Storage
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());

        // Time
        try
        {
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.w("TestClient", "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
        }

        // Roster Exchange
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());

        // Message Events
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());

        // Chat State
        pm.addExtensionProvider("active", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        pm.addExtensionProvider("composing", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        pm.addExtensionProvider("paused", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        pm.addExtensionProvider("gone", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        // XHTML
        pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

        // Group Chat Invitations
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());

        // Service Discovery # Items
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());

        // Service Discovery # Info
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());

        // Data Forms
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());

        // MUC User
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());

        // MUC Admin
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());

        // MUC Owner
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());

        // Delayed Delivery
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());

        // Version
        try
        {
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            // Not sure what's happening here.
        }

        // VCard
        pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());

        // Offline Message Requests
        pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());

        // Offline Message Indicator
        pm.addExtensionProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());

        // Last Activity
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());

        // User Search
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());

        // SharedGroupsInfo
        pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup", "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

        // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
        pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses", "http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());

        // FileTransfer
        pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());

        pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());

        // Privacy
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());

        pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());

        pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());

        pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());

        // archive
        pm.addIQProvider("list", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ListIQProvider());

        pm.addIQProvider("chat", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ChatIQProvider());

    }
}
```

@HirenPatel

first you need to add the **archive plugin** to **Openfire**.
Then after the **Xmpp connection** in the **client** you must **register** your **providers** including the one that helps retrieve the chat messages:

```
pm.addIQProvider("list", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ListIQProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("chat", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ChatIQProvider());
```

Then you need to send an IQ stanza like follow:

```
final IQ iq = new IQ()
{

    @Override public String getChildElementXML()
    {

        return "<retrieve  xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' with='test@customOpenfire.com'><set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'><max xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>30</max></set> </retrieve>";

    }
};

iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
iq.setPacketID("987654321");

xmppConnection.sendPacket(iq);
```

Comment: Hi, where do you get the result of pm.addIQProvider("list", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ListIQProvider());. You have the code of ListIQProvider?

Comment: Hi Anna. The comment was too long so I added it to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks, but I continue without understand where you put this line: pm.addIQProvider("chat", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ChatIQProvider());

Comment: No they are not the same. ChatIQ contains one chat with a body which is the actual content of the message. While ListIQ contains a llist of chats without the body.


Which IQ Stanza? If you are referring to the Stanza I send to recover the archive both the list and retrieve ones are in the opening question.

Comment: @Miro, How can I integrate it ?

Comment: @HirenPatel Can you please elaborate? What is it you need to integrate and where?

Comment: @Miro, I want the chat history in android application, I tried but I was unable to get it, I want it when user logged in with openfire server, can you please help me ?

Comment: @HirenPatel Sure, it's been a long time since I used aSmack and Openfire, but I'll see what I can recall.
Check the end of the answer above.